# How to filter SSAS data on the server?

Tags: ssas, componentone, ssas-2008

I'm new to the world of Data Warehousing. I've built a Cube using SQL Sever Analysis Server and displaying the reports using [GrapeCity's Active Analysis](http://www.gcpowertools.com/products/ActiveAnalysis). I would like to know how can I filter the data programmatically? Similar to a where clause in a relational database query? I have a PivotView that will be used for running reports by many users across many divisions and I would like to filter the data to the user's division. What's the best approach? Should I be creating different cubes per division? That doesn't seem to scale very well as the number of divisions are constantly changing. What other options do I have?

Comment: I deleted my answer. Yes roles are based on computer users, but if cube can get any other information from http.... or some other  apliccation like GrapeCity's Active Analysis,  I don't know. So I think you should search that SSAS (cube) can get some data from other applications, about this I'm very doubt, because microsoft just for microsoft products, maybe there are some tool from enthusiast. Also you can always search for freelancer programmer who can build for money such a tool... This is all what I can say, Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

I have done both.  I have created multiple cubes per division for some, it sounds like you are against that and I can understand why.

I would recommend just having different mdx queries for each division (aka different reports for each division).  Basically, the same query, but a splice in the query like this. :

[Division].[Division Id].&[1]

Creating multiple reports is kind of a pain also, if you did SSRS you could create just one report and create the report dynamically and it could figure out what division the user was in and filter out the data that way.

HTH